# passive voice (general truth)

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

I am not a native speaker of English, and I'm having a hard time learning "Passive voice." Please help me. Thanks!

- It is known as the black star.
- It is used as an adhesive.

Are they both in Passive voice form or can they also be:

- It was known as the black star.
- It was used as an adhesive.

Answer (score 1):

All of the given examples are already in the passive voice form, but the only difference is that the first two sentences are in present simple tense while the last two sentences are in past simple tense.